# Jmeter - extract a value using RegEx from a response which has no characters on the right

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to extract the value of "D/123"
from a response ID=D/123

Comment: [Try to Solve The Problem First](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) 
-- 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
-- 
[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
--
[I Downvoted Because](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: I tried RegEx ID=(.*?) which isn’t working. Please could someone help? Should I be trying any special character at the end?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by trying a regex `ID=(\S+)`.